# Code compiles, however crashes after start(rot13)

Tags: c++, rot13

So, I have been fiddling around with a code for a ctf competition. However, every time I run the actual console application, it keeps crashing. Could someone please explain to me why. Thank you so much in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int lowerConvert(char x)
{
    int y;

    if (x == 'a')
        y = 1;
    if (x == 'b')
        y = 2;
    if (x == 'c')
        y = 3;
    if (x == 'd')
        y = 4;
    if (x == 'e')
        y = 5;
    if (x == 'f')
        y = 6;
    if (x == 'g')
        y = 7;
    if (x == 'h')
        y = 8;
    if (x == 'i')
        y = 9;
    if (x == 'j')
        y = 10;
    if (x =='k')
        y = 11;
    if (x == 'l')
        y = 12;
    if (x == 'm')
        y = 13;
    if (x == 'n')
        y = 14;
    if (x == 'o')
        y = 15;
    if (x == 'p')
        y = 16;
    if (x == 'q')
        y = 17;
    if (x == 'r')
        y = 18;
    if (x == 's')
        y = 19;
    if (x == 't')
        y = 20;
    if (x == 'u')
        y = 21;
    if (x == 'v')
        y = 22;
    if (x == 'w')
        y = 23;
    if (x == 'x')
        y = 24;
    if (x == 'y')
        y = 25;
    if (x == 'z')
        y = 26;

    return y;

}
int upperConvert(char x)
{
    int y;

    if (x == 'A')
        y = 27;
    if (x == 'B')
        y = 28;
    if (x == 'C')
        y = 29;
    if (x == 'D')
        y = 30;
    if (x == 'E')
        y = 31;
    if (x == 'F')
        y = 32;
    if (x == 'G')
        y = 33;
    if (x == 'H')
        y = 34;
    if (x == 'I')
        y = 35;
    if (x == 'J')
        y = 36;
    if (x == 'K')
        y = 37;
    if (x == 'L')
        y = 38;
    if (x == 'M')
        y = 39;
    if (x == 'N')
        y = 40;
    if (x == 'O')
        y = 41;
    if (x == 'P')
        y = 42;
    if (x == 'Q')
        y = 43;
    if (x == 'R')
        y = 44;
    if (x == 'S')
        y = 45;
    if (x == 'T')
        y = 46;
    if (x == 'U')
        y = 47;
    if (x == 'V')
        y = 48;
    if (x == 'W')
        y = 49;
    if (x == 'X')
        y = 50;
    if (x == 'Y')
        y = 51;
    if (x == 'Z')
        y = 52;

    return y;
}
char lowerBack(int x)
{
    char y;

    if (x == 1)
        y = 'a';
    else if (x == 2)
        y = 'b';
    else if (x == 3)
        y = 'c';
    else if (x == 4)
        y = 'd';
    else if (x == 5)
        y = 'e';
    else if (x == 6)
        y = 'f';
    else if (x == 7)
        y = 'g';
    else if (x == 8)
        y = 'h';
    else if (x == 9)
        y = 'i';
    else if (x == 10)
        y = 'j';
    else if (x == 11)
        y = 'k';
    else if (x == 12)
        y = 'l';
    else if (x == 13)
        y = 'm';
    else if (x == 14)
        y = 'n';
    else if (x == 15)
        y = 'o';
    else if (x == 16)
        y = 'p';
    else if (x == 17)
        y = 'q';
    else if (x == 18)
        y = 'r';
    else if (x == 19)
        y = 's';
    else if (x == 20)
        y = 't';
    else if (x == 21)
        y = 'u';
    else if (x == 22)
        y = 'v';
    else if (x == 23)
        y = 'w';
    else if (x == 24)
        y = 'x';
    else if (x == 25)
        y = 'y';
    else if (x == 26)
        y = 'z';

        return y;
}
char upperBack(int x)
{
    char y;
    if (x == 27)
        y = 'A';
    if (x == 28)
        y = 'B';
    if (x == 29)
        y = 'C';
    if (x == 30)
        y = 'D';
    if (x == 31)
        y = 'E';
    if (x == 32)
        y = 'F';
    if (x == 33)
        y = 'G';
    if (x == 34)
        y = 'H';
    if (x == 35)
        y = 'I';
    if (x == 36)
        y = 'J';
    if (x == 37)
        y = 'K';
    if (x == 38)
        y = 'L';
    if (x == 39)
        y = 'M';
    if (x == 40)
        y = 'N';
    if (x == 41)
        y = 'O';
    if (x == 42)
        y = 'P';
    if (x == 43)
        y = 'Q';
    if (x == 44)
        y = 'R';
    if (x == 45)
        y = 'S';
    if (x == 46)
        y = 'T';
    if (x == 47)
        y = 'U';
    if (x == 48)
        y = 'V';
    if (x == 49)
        y = 'W';
    if (x == 50)
        y = 'X';
    if (x == 51)
        y = 'Y';
    if (x == 52)
        y = 'Z';


    return y;
}

 void primaryRot13()
{
    cout << "Please enter name of file to be decrypted: ";
    string name;
    getline(cin, name);

    name += ".txt";

    ifstream file;
    ofstream write;
    file.open(name);

    string message;

    file >> message;

    int converted[9999999];
    char reconvert[9999999];

    for (int i = 0; i < message.length();++i)
    {
        if (message[i] == 0 || 1 || 2 || 3 || 4 || 5 || 6 || 7 || 8 || 9)
            message[i] += 53;

        if (message[i] == 'a' || 'b' || 'c' || 'd' || 'e' || 'f' || 'g' || 'h' || 'i' || 'j' || 'k' || 'l' || 'm' || 'n' || 'o' || 'p' || 'q' || 'r' || 's' || 't' || 'u' || 'v' || 'w' || 'x' || 'y' || 'z')
        converted[i] = lowerConvert(message[i]);    
        converted[i] += 13;
        if (converted[i] > 26)
            converted[i] -= 26;

        if (message[i] == 'A' || 'B' || 'C' || 'D' || 'E' || 'F' || 'G' || 'H' || 'I' || 'J' || 'K' || 'L' || 'M' || 'N' || 'O' || 'P' || 'Q' || 'R' || 'S' || 'T' || 'U' || 'V' || 'W' || 'X' || 'Y' || 'Z')
            converted[i] = upperConvert(message[i]);
        converted[i] += 13;
        if (converted[i] > 52)
            converted[i] -= 26;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); ++i)
    {
        if (converted[i] == 52 || 53 || 54 || 55 || 56 || 57 || 58 || 59 || 60 || 61){
            reconvert[i] = converted[i] - 53;
            continue;
        }
        if (converted[i] < 27){
            reconvert[i] = lowerBack(converted[i]);
            continue;
        }
        if (converted[i] < 51){
            reconvert[i] = upperBack(converted[i]);
            continue;
        }
        write.open("decode");
        write << reconvert[i];

    }


}
```

***EDIT AND FINAL SOLUTION***
Several years later, I am here to repost. What I ended up doing was simply adding the desired amount to the character code, then if it is greater than the upper limit for that set, I subtracted 26 in order to reset. I also ended up using the vector instead, which did solve my issue of crashing. Now I can happily rot13 all day long :) All without the myriad of if statements.

Comment: Before anyone asks, no it is not homework, and yes I have been doing research and actually trying.

Comment: You've got to be kidding, all those `if` statements.  How about some mathematics an a modulo operator?

Comment: `primaryRot13` requires approximately 49 megabytes of stack.  That's probably more than your OS permits you to allocate.

Comment: Wow! You need to learn to be *much* lazier. ROT13 should take no more than about...13 lines of code (total). Could probably do it in 1 if you really wanted to (and didn't care about EBCDIC, which most people don't).

Comment: I mean I was in class and a bit bored in all honesty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Table Lookup

First, an introduction to table or array look ups.
Given a character array:

```
static const char letters[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
```

The index of 'a' is 0, 'b' is 1, ..., 'z' is 25.
The array can be searched for a letter.  The index of the letter can be it's number.  In your case, it would be the index + 1.

Example:

```
static const unsigned int letter_quantity = sizeof(letters) / sizeof(letters[0]);
unsigned int index = 0;
for (index = 0; index < letter_quantity; ++i)
{
  if (letters[i] == x)
  {
    break;
  }
}
```

At the end of the loop statement, the `index` variable will be the position of the character in `x` or the length of the array (if not found).

### Modulo Arithmetic

Modulo arithmetic, using the `%` operator, returns the remainder.  It has the behavior of *wrapping around*.  This can be used with the array.

```
unsigned int new_char_index = index + 13;  // We may have gone past the array.
new_char_index = new_char_index % letter_quantity; // Wrap around.
```

### The New ROT13 Character

The converted character can be found by using the `new_char_index` as the index into the array.

```
char rot13 = letters[new_char_index];
```

### Covering all the characters

The remaining uppercase characters can be added to the array to account for all the letters.  Other symbols can be added also.

All this without any `if` statements.

Answer (score 1):

You're allocating two static arrays of 9999999 elements on the [*stack*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap).

If an `int` is 32 bits and a `char` is 8 bits on your system, then that's 48MB of memory. That's simply too much for the stack.

Try allocating your arrays dynamically instead, i.e. using [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/):

```
std::vector<int> converted(9999999);
std::vector<char> reconvert(9999999);
```

Comment: We have yet to learn about vectors in class, but I'll do some research. Thank you :) Admittedly, I also had 1 too many nines in there, than what I needed.

Comment: They're actually easier to use than raw C-style arrays, simply because they're harder to misuse. (Especially when you use [`at`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/at/) instead of [`[]`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator[]/) to access the elements.) Btw with one nine less, they're still 5MB, still too much for the stack :P

Comment: Ah okay, thank you. And yeah, i ended up setting it to 200,000 as i need somewhere around 179,000 give or take.